# How to sum of dict values into list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Consider the following function:

I need to determine the sum for each year in the range of years taken as input.

So for example, `sumarry_statistics(data, 2015, 2020)`

I need to find the sum of `col[9]` for each tuple in a list of tuples that has `[0]` in that range of years.

So I have this much, which works to create my first list of tuples that counts each year, and how many time that year occurred:

```
def summary_statistics(data, year_start, year_end):
    earthquake_count_by_year = []
    total_damages_by_year = []
    casualties_by_year = []
    year_count = {}
    dmg_sum = {}
    
    years = []
    year_start = int(year_start)
    year_end = int(year_end)
    
    if year_end >= year_start:
        
        #store year range into list
        years = list(range(year_start, year_end+1))
        
        for index, tuple in enumerate(data):
            #values to be summed for each year in dmg_sum
            yr = tuple[0]
            dmgs = tuple[9]
            
            #if year in range of years (year_start - year_end)
            if tuple[0] in years:
                #if year does not exist in dict, set it to 0
                if tuple[0] not in year_count:
                    year_count[tuple[0]] = 0
                #count number of occurences for each year
                year_count[tuple[0]] += 1
       earthquake_count_by_year = list(year_count.items())
```

Output of print(earthquake_count_by_year):

```
[(2015, 48), (2016, 52), (2017, 64), (2018, 65), (2019, 60), (2020, 24)]
```

I need to write something similar, but instead of counting the number of occurrences, i need to find the sum of of `col[9]` for each year taken as input.

I don't know what to do after this:

```
for index, tuple in enumerate(data):
    #values to be summed for each year in dmg_sum
    yr = tuple[0]
    dmgs = tuple[9]
    
    #if year in range of years (year_start - year_end)
    if tuple[0] in years:
        #if year does not exist in dict, set it to 0
        if tuple[0] not in year_count:
            year_count[tuple[0]] = 0
        #count number of occurences for each year
        year_count[tuple[0]] += 1
        
        if tuple[0] not in dmg_sum:
            dmg_sum[tuple[0]] += sum(dmg_sum.values())
```

that last line is especially problematic for me. It does not work. I don't think I was even very clearly able to describe what I need to do here. `tuple[0]` is a csv column with a list of years. `tuple[9]` is a list of integers representing number of deaths. I need to find number of deaths for each year taken as input and store in same fashion, list of tuples like:

```
[(year, sum of [9]), (year2, sum of [9]), etc.
```

Comment: is tuple[0] a list of years or a specific year?

Comment: From what I understand it is a specific year, so your code cannot work. Anyway you can't  add value to something that doesn't already exist in `dmg_sum[tuple[0]] += sum(dmg_sum.values())`

Comment: Ah ok so I don't what it is doing. Provide full code so we can test it ourselves, provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: well, actually, tuple[0] is a specific year... but it just iterates through the range of years.... so ... your solution below actually worked.

Comment: ah ok, so glad it worked, try to be a little be more structured in the presentation of your code next time, and provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
if tuple[0] not in dmg_sum:
    dmg_sum[tuple[0]] = dmgs
else:
    dmg_sum[tuple[0]] += dmgs
```

EDIT: Adding a little bit more information regarding the answer and the context
You can't add a value to a variable that is not yet assigned, in:

```
if tuple[0] not in dmg_sum:
        dmg_sum[tuple[0]] += dmgs
```

And you iterate over data which contains a specific year `tuple[0]` and a number representing number of deaths `tuple[9]` so for each iteration of the for loop, if your conditions are respected, if the key representing the dictionary where you want to assign the data doesn't exist you add it and assign the corresponding data, i.e `dmgs`, else you add that data to it

Be careful with the variable name you take to iterate over `data` in:

```
for index, tuple in enumerate(data):
```

`tuple` is a python builtin for the tuple object, so when you create that variable with that name you override the `tuple` python builtin with the same name